# My web.config transform doesn't work

Tags: web-config

I'm using a web.config transform to change a link in the production environment but when previewing it, the transformation doesn't happen..

Here is my code:

web.Test.config

```
  <configuration>
    <appSettings>
      <add key ="ELeg" value ="1"/>
    </appSettings>
  </configuration>
  <system.web>
```

web.Prod.config

```
  <configuration>
    <appSettings>
      <add key ="ELeg" value="10" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
    </appSettings>
  </configuration>
```

When previewing it on the prod and test envoirment, it doesnt add the appSetting.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

**UPDATE**

Here is my entire Test transform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- For more information on using web.config transformation visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=125889 -->

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <!--
    In the example below, the "SetAttributes" transform will change the value of 
    "connectionString" to use "ReleaseSQLServer" only when the "Match" locator 
    finds an attribute "name" that has a value of "MyDB".

    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyDB" 
        connectionString="Data Source=ReleaseSQLServer;Initial Catalog=MyReleaseDB;Integrated Security=True" 
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>
  -->

  <configuration>
    <appSettings>
      <add key ="ELeg" value ="1" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
    </appSettings>
  </configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
    <!--
      In the example below, the "Replace" transform will replace the entire 
      <customErrors> section of your web.config file.
      Note that because there is only one customErrors section under the 
      <system.web> node, there is no need to use the "xdt:Locator" attribute.

      <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
        mode="RemoteOnly" xdt:Transform="Replace">
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
      </customErrors>
    -->
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have a key=`10` to match on, you have a key=`ELeg`;

In other words, this (untested) transform should work better;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <add key ="ELeg" value ="10" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(value)" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Explanation of the transform attributes

```
xdt:Locator="Match(key)"               // Find elements with matching `key`.
xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(value)"   // Set the `value` attribute on the matches
```

EDIT: If you want to insert it and it does not even exist, then a plain `xdt:Transform="Insert"` is what you want;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <add key ="ELeg" value ="10" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you. However I realized that the problem was not that it shows as the same value as the Test web.config. The problem is that it doesnt show the appSettings at all. I think there it would be better to have a `xdt:Transform="Insert(value)"`instead of `xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(value)"`.becase I need to add the appSetting and not replace any old one (there is no appSetting in the original web.config) Am I correct?

Comment: @Simon.S Added an example of that (if I understood your question correctly)

Comment: Thank you.. I get error: "No element in the source document matches '/configuration/configuration/appSettings'

Comment: @Simon.S Hm, how is that section nested in the transform file? Inside another configuration element with the xdt namespace?

Comment: Updated my question and included my transform

Comment: The inner <configuration> tag should be removed, otherwise it will together with the configuration tag around the entire file nest down to configuration/configuration/appsettings instead of configuration/appsettings.

Answer (score 1):

Below will transform the value of the ELeg setting to 10:

`<add xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" key="ELeg" value="10" />`

Comment: Yeah, sorry my bad there. I was replacing my actual value with random letters to just give example on how it would look like. Please see my updated question.